# How does tax work with donations?

Tags: united-states, taxes, gift-tax

My understanding of the gift tax is that the donor has to pay the tax, but up to a limit they don't have to pay tax.

I'm a developer.  Suppose I offer my software/libraries/blog for free on my site and have the option to donate via PayPal, Patreon, or whatever.  Is that money considered a gift and therefore tax free?

Comment: [How should I handle taxes for Minecraft server donations?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16282/how-should-i-handle-taxes-for-minecraft-server-donations) appears to be nearly identical in nature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Donations, particularly those in the context of you providing a free service (software, libraries, etc.) are a notable grey area in tax code.

Simply naming a button "Donate" doesn't necessarily classify the money transfer as a "gift". The IRS can decide that it's money you're being paid to continue your excellent work/service, making it taxable income (unless you're a registered non-profit organization).

In the instance of Patreon, and many other crowd-funding services, you're providing a certain level of "service" for each tier of donations (such as early access or something, I'm not sure what you're offering), which means they're receiving consideration for their donations, which most likely makes it fall into taxable income (again, unless you're a registered non-profit organization).

State tax law is even more convoluted, and you should consult your tax professional for clarification on your specific situation.

Comment: Would having a disclaimer on the donate screen about "this is considered gift for tax purposes" make any difference, or is it just ultimately up to the IRS to decide

Comment: It's ultimately up to them. Remember, the IRS tells you how your income is classified, not the other way around.

Comment: I was hoping it was written such that it allowed it.  A grey area is riskier... Thanks for the response!

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Claiming something doesn't make it true. If it did, everybody with a job could save a whole lot of tax by agreeing to work for the minimum wage and accepting an additional monthly gift from their employer.

Comment: You will notice that even major nonprofits are extremely careful to say that PART OF your gift MAY be deductable AS PERMITTED BY LAW, and may or may not go the extra step of suggesting people check with their financial advisors. You aren't claiming deductability, but their caution should warn you that it's unsafe to make any strong statement.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes if I was only saying something without meaning it.  I know it sounds like I'm just trying to evade taxes, but I do believe there is a distinction between requiring someone to pay for a service and legitimately offering all services for free and allowing people to give me money at their discretion.  Unfortunately I do see the possibility of this being gamed in an example like the one you presented.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas there's no distinction tax-wise. You're free to set any price you want for your services, but it is still services.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas The distinction is between selling your services for a fixed price and letting the customer decide the price. You're doing the latter but you're still selling the service.

Comment: Someone deleted my comments... interesting.

Comment: The ongoing comments are adding nothing to the answer, and should be brought to a chat room.

Answer (score 6):

"Donate" buttons are meaningless with regards to taxes. This is payment for something you provided, and you cannot claim that you've received a gift.

Any money you receive in this way is payment for your software. Remember, for gifts - no consideration should have been provided to the donor. Anything for which a consideration was provided - cannot be a gift. In your case the consideration is the software, and it's value is the amount you were paid. Since every person can decide how much to pay you on his own - any payment is for the software, not a gift.

Any money you get is taxable to you, and you cannot claim it as "gifts" without exposing yourself to risks of making fraudulent claims.

Consult a licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in your State) for a qualified tax advice.

Comment: Does that still apply even if the "consideration" would be provided with or without the payment, as in this case?  If my 5-year-old niece gives me a drawing she made, and I give her $20 for her birthday, does that mean my $20 was not a gift?  Can you suggest an official source that clarifies this?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes I agree. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment Saying "money you recieve ... is payment" is incorrect because I didn't exchange my software for their money.  I am provisioning the service/software free of charge.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas - You are welcome to reject a correct answer here, that's your choice. But to be clear, littleadv's answer is dead on right. In this situation there is no grey area. Money received for what we used to call "shareware" is taxable. Period. The only question is whether the recipient chooses to report it or to break the law. Nate's comment is an absurd analogy. And your WikiPedia link, equally meaningless. If you wish, cite IRS regulations, not a definition of payment.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas of course you did. Would they give you the money without you offering the software?

Comment: @littleadv Would they have not gotten the software without paying me?

Comment: @Nate Sec. 61 of the Internal Revenue Code.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas That's irrelevant. They valued your software at $X and paid you for that. The fact that you didn't set a price and let the buyer decide how much to pay doesn't make it any less a sale.

Comment: http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/rr-07-19.pdf the first line says "... in exchange for ...".  This is NOT in exchange for anything.  To "exchange" requires that there is a requirement on both sides to hold up the bargain.  There is no requirement on either side.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas but there is. You exchanged software for money.

Comment: No they didn't.  "You exchanged X for Y" means both X,Y had to be there in order for it to happen.  That is not the case.  You'd have to prove that I wouldn't make the software without the donation in order for you to claim that. It comes down to how you define exchange.  I have not found a definition from the IRS.  If you have one I would love to read it.

Comment: @Carlos, you're confusing things. **you** are making a gift. You giving the software for free is independent of payment and would happen with or without it. **They** are not making a gift. They would **not** give you the money had you not gave them the software. The definition of gross income is in IRC sec. 61. Exclusions are explicit, you don't need to look for a definition of "exchange", you need to look for a definition of "gift".

Comment: Gift: "Any transfer to an individual, either directly or indirectly, where full consideration (measured in money or money's worth) is not received in return." http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Frequently-Asked-Questions-on-Gift-Taxes#2  Like you said, I'm gifting them the software.  So they could not be receiving the software in return for the money they gave me because they received that as a gift.  So they aren't receiving anything in return.  Therefore their money is a gift.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas you're trying to convince yourself or something? Do what you want, it's your problem when you get audited. They *received* the software, and *because of that* donated you money. Cause and effect. So they definitely received consideration for the donation.

Comment: From the handful of laws mentioned I'm convinced that I should ask a lawyer before starting something like this.  For what its worth, I wasn't attacking you personally and I do appreciate the time you put into the discussion.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas lawyer? What on earth for? Tax adviser. EA/CPA is enough, no need to pay tons of money to an attorney.